# I imported old files into the S3 bucket - how can I access them with filepicker API?

Tags: filepicker.io

I have old files prior filepicker what I now copied to the S3 bucket. Can I access them with the filepicker API to get them cropped?

I didn't find any relevant info in the documentation. According to the Stackoverflow threads, it seems I should store them again. Is it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use filepicker.io conversion feature file has to be available via filepicker API.

So first store amazon url:
    https://s3.amazonaws.com/your_own_bucket/ZynOv436QOirPYbJIr3Y_5qYoopVTsixCJJiqSWSE.png

Using Filepicker REST API:

```
curl -X POST -d url="https://s3.amazonaws.com/your_own_bucket/ZynOv436QOirPYbJIr3Y_5qYoopVTsixCJJiqSWSE.png" https://www.filepicker.io/api/store/S3?key=MY_API_KEY
```

Sample response:

```
{"container": "kg_bucket", "url": "https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/EmlSqNgR0CcgiKJQ70aV", "filename": "ZynOv436QOirPYbJIr3Y_5qYoopVTsixCJJiqSWSE.png", "key": "ILeMnXRB7ucPF1ILzQ9a_ZynOv436QOirPYbJIr3Y_5qYoopVTsixCJJiqSWSE.png", "type": "image/png", "size": 175210}
```

Now you can convert filepicker url https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/EmlSqNgR0CcgiKJQ70aV

Using GET request
https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/EmlSqNgR0CcgiKJQ70aV/convert?w=200&h=250

Or using POST request to store converted file

```
curl -X POST "https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/EmlSqNgR0CcgiKJQ70aV/convert?format=jpg&quality=30&storeLocation=S3&storePath=/myFolder/myFile.png?key=MY_API_KEY"
```

Comment: Is this mean that Filepicker will copy my files from S3 again or it just creates a Filepicker URL for them? I need the second option :)

Comment: Yes, second option creates new file and store it under your s3. The response will be similar to store method response. Using GET request https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/EmlSqNgR0CcgiKJQ70aV/convert?w=200&h=250 return converted file from Filepicker conversion servers. Once you request file with specific parameters it is cached for one month. And the file is hosted on our S3 buckets.